# How can I boot from my bootable USB flash drive to install Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, boot

I have downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 image, but I cannot install it.

I've tried burning it to a pen drive, but when I reboot with it in place, it just boots into Windows! I've also tried burning it to a DVD, but my computer acts as if the DVD is not bootable.

I've tried using 'wubi', but after about 10-15 minutes it gives the error:

```
permission denied- for more info visit the log file
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: dats da log file....

Answer (score 1):

To boot from USB you need to prepare it. Directly copying the image to USB won't make it bootable.

Two most used software that helps to create USB bootable

- [Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)
- [LILI](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)

Once USB is prepared, you need to open BIOS and select the USB drive as first bootable disk. Then it will boot using the USB.

For wubi installer 12.10, you need to download wubi installer. Copy the iso image to same directory as installer and execute wubi.exe as admin. Installation from wubi.exe inside the iamge is blocked due to few bugs.

**Caution : Windows 8 preinstalled laptop require special steps.**

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible problems you may be experiencing, from the information in your question and in comments.

[Web-E's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/234648/22949) explains how to install Ubuntu *alongside* Windows. I recommend doing that--it seems to be what you intended to do first.

### Wubi Troubleshooting

If you did want to install Ubuntu inside Windows with Wubi, and you are using Windows Vista or later, the `permission denied` error can often be fixed by right-clicking `Wubi.exe` and clicking *Run as Administrator*. Running `Wubi.exe` with normal abilities when [UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-User-Account-Control) is enabled will fail.

If that doesn't work, then you must consult the log file that the error message referred to, to see what is wrong. It should have been created in the same folder that contains `Wubi.exe` itself. If you can make sense of what the log file tells you, you may be able to solve the problem. Otherwise, you should edit your question to include the text from the log file, or post it at http://paste.ubuntu.com and add a link to it in your question. (You can then comment here to notify me.)

With all that said, remember, unless you *want* a Wubi system, I recommend you install a normal Ubuntu system alongside Windows by creating and booting from a USB flash drive (or CD/DVD) as explain in Web-E's answer.

### Inability to Boot Ubuntu After Installing Alongside Windows

Web-E and I had both thought you meant that when you created the bootable USB flash drive to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, you were unable to boot *from it* and start the installation.

However, if the problem is that you can install Ubuntu but when you try to boot it, it just boots into Windows, this is caused by Ubuntu's boot loader, GRUB2, not being installed to the master boot record. To solve the problem:

- [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

  (The same problem happens when Windows is installed *after* Ubuntu and replaces GRUB2 with its own boot loader, configured to boot just Windows. That's the reason for the seemingly unrelated title.)

Or if you prefer, you can instead any of these methods:

- [Grub2/Installing - Fixing a Broken System](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System)

Comment: First thanks for answering....second, yes i want it along with windows but as i said i tried booting from a USB & a DVD image but it wont work i can't understand why !! can u help with that it consider the DVD not there & the USB says it will restart to install then it restarts & open windows normally ??

Comment: @AhmedAshraf If the problem is that you *can* boot from the USB flash drive and install Ubuntu, but you cannot *restart* and boot into your new Ubuntu system, I've added a second to explain how to fix that problem. Unfortunately, we're guessing at what your problem is because you're not giving enough details for us to really know what's going on. If this doesn't solve the problem, please edit your question and provide as many details as possible about everything you have tried to do, what you did to accomplish it, and what happened. Explain what you've done and what happened step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments I understood that you are just inserting the pen-drive but you are not changing the boot priority. When you power ON the system look at the first screen where it says you to hit either F1,F2,ESC,F10 or 'DEL' to enter Setup, Once you are in Boot Setup select Boot Features and give your usb as first priority.Here's a reference link to Enter the BIOS Setup http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange_2.htm. could you please let me know the windows version you have.